# Best tool for building a PDF reader web app

Tags: javascript, pdf, html, web, css

I need to create a web application that conceptually is simple: i need a web application which has a page with a list of pdf, the user can select a pdf and the web app will show it in a nice looking pdf reader embedded on the page.

Also which tech stack and DB suits the best for this kind of task? Because in this application the admin is able to upload to the DB the pdf via a page which is a super minimal admin panel then the main application fetches the pdf files from this DB and can be read.

Is there an api/library/extension which permits me to manage the pdf viewer in the web app.

Kindly have a look at these 2 images they will clearify my needs

This is the main architecture:
[image: This is the complete architecture]

The Pdfs ui on the main page should look like this:
[image: And this is how the pdfs should look like on main pge]

Comment: Are you looking for a paid solution or something available at no cost?  Also are you looking to develop this from the bottom-up or something ready to go out of the box?

Comment: paid or free to use it doesn't matter...the main application is developed by me but i was looking for a 3rd party library/extension/tool that manages all the hassle for viewing the pdf in a pdf format with all the options (like the options u get in acrobat)

Comment: also what is the mechanism to store-fetch a document in the DB (in this case a pdf doc) for example how would i handle uploading a pdf on mysql and then fetching and displaying it with that 3rd party tool

Comment: The LEADTOOLS JavaScript Document Viewer allows creating a PDF web viewer. The viewer is managed by a service on the backend, which provides a wide range of features, including the ability to use [caching](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/to/document-toolkit-and-caching.html). You could load the documents from your DB to this cache to make use of this feature. If you are interested in this, you can find [online demos](https://www.leadtools.com/demos/html5) and a [free evaluation](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads) on the website. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor).